# A Group of Length $1$ with a Subgroup of Length $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I am trying to find a group $G$ which has a composition series of length $1$, but has a subgroup with a composition series of length $m$ for all $m\geq 2$. I know that length $G=1 \implies G$ is simple since the composition series of $G$ would be $G=G_0 \triangleleft G_1=\{1\}$. Thus for $G$ to have a subgroup $H$ with length $m$, I know $H$ must not be normal in $G$. I am hoping to find a group $G$ with a non-normal subgroup $H \simeq C_n$ where $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ where $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i = m$ for distinct primes $p_i$ since this is the length of $C_n$. Note $C_n$ is the cyclic subgroup of order $n$ (think $\mathbb{Z}_n$).

I was looking at different alternating groups in forms $A_{2^m+1}$ and $A_{2m+1}$. They are guaranteed to be simple for $m\geq 2$, but I am wondering if they always have such a cyclic subgroup. If they do, what is the subgroup?

If I am wrong about the alternating groups, what other groups do satisfy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What with the  "standard" embedding of $\;A_4\;$ in $\;A_5\;$ ?

$$1\le V\lhd A_4\le A_5\;,\;\;V:=\{\,(12)(34)\,,\,(13)(24)\,,\,(14)(23)\,\}$$

Comment: How would I generalize this for any $m\geq 2$?

Comment: @OnyxDown I don't know. I'm not even sure it can be done.

Comment: Hmm, "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by W. Keith Nicholson seems to suggest that there is an answer to my question, but does not say anything about this specific embedding (or any hint at all). But thank you for the idea!

Comment: To generalize it, let $H$ be any finite group with composition length $m$ and embed it in an alternating group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Excellent, as usual. I don't know if I can embed $\;H\;$ directly in an alternating group, but I know I can embed it in $\;S_m\;$ for some $\;m\in\Bbb N\;$ , and then I can embed this permutations group in $\;A_{m+2}\;$ . Thank you very much.